# Facebook iframe page_fan in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to make a check in a facebook application iframe tab to check if a user like a particular page or not, I am putting the following

```
FB.init({
    appId : '205563326143108',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});

function checkFan() {
    FB.api(
    { 
        method: 'fql.query', 
        query: 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid= ' + user_id + ' AND page_id=124571914229443' 
        },
    function(result) {
        if (result.length) { 
         document.getElementById('fan').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
         document.getElementById('non_fan').style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}
```

FB.init seem to be working as I am using it for other things but checkFan function is not working.

Can someone help me please as I have been trying to make it work for a long period of time and I surrender finding solutions :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pages.isFan` instead:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'pages.isFan',
    page_id: '124571914229443',
    uid: user_id
}, function (resp) {
    if (resp == true) {
        document.getElementById('fan').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (resp.error_code) {
        alert(resp.error_msg);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('non_fan').style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi I have tried it and didn't work, it seem when I am making the call to checkFan() its not going through FB.api( fuction as it like it is ignoring it. Any idea why?

Comment: I have another function that is working
when using 

 FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',

but this one is not :(

Comment: I tested this code and it worked for me. Try abstracting out the callback function and using firebug so set a breakpoint inside it to see if it ever gets hit?

Comment: Its telling me user_id is not defined when I checked

Comment: You have to actually get the user_id from somewhere eg. https://graph.facebook.com/me after authentication - and then pulling the id off of the JSON object returned

Comment: I surrender no idea how to call it :(

Comment: My problem is authentication now as to authenticate I need to user FB.login which is some browsers is not showing as they have popup blockers

Comment: Then you will likely need to redirect the entire page and use the redirect_uri to return to your page on successful authentication.